# Get selected value in dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html, json

I would like to put a button to change the language on the page but I have a problem.
I can't understand how to implement the "select" - "option".

this is the code JS:

```
function checkAlert(evt) {
    var strUser = evt.options[evt.selectedIndex].value;
    Traduction(strUser);
}

function Traduction(index) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            ShowJson(this.responseText);
        }
    };
    var counter;
    switch (index) {
        case 1:
            counter = "./Traduction/Fr.json";
            break;
        case 2:
            counter = "./Traduction/Nl.json";
            break;
        case 3:
            counter = "./Traduction/En.json";
            break;
        default:
            counter = "./Traduction/En.json";
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", counter, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
function ShowJson(JsonData) {

    var obj = JSON.parse(JsonData);
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = obj.p1;
    document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = obj.p2;

}
```

and this is the HTML :

```
    <div class="Title" id="TextTitle">
        <h1>This is the title</h1>
        <div class="Menu">
            <select class="Language" id='Language' onchange="checkAlert(this);">
                <option value='1'>FR</option>
                <option value='2'>NL</option>
                <option value='3' selected='selected'>EN</option>
            </select>
            <select class="Style" id='Style'>
                <option value='1' selected='selected'>Style 1</option>
                <option value='2'>Style 2</option>
                <option value='3'>Style 3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Can you help me please?
Thank you

Comment: Your question is clear to me. What the issue here?

Comment: I have this error :
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at ShowJson (script.js:32)
    at XMLHttpRequest.Traduction.xhttp.onreadystatechange (script.js:10)

Comment: can you post the json response?

Comment: the three file contains
{
  "p1": "this is the first paragraph",
  "p2": "this is the second paragraph"
}
{
  "p1": "Ceci est le premièr paragraph",
  "p2": "Ceci est le deuxième paragraph"
}
{
  "p1": "dit is de eerste alinea",
  "p2": "dit is de tweede alinea"
}

Comment: it catch only the default case